# In French, how do you say "Don't say you weren't warned!"?

Tags: expressions

In conversation with my colleagues, I just said the following:

> Si vous y tenez vraiment, c'est pas moi qui vais vous en décourager. Mais ***je vous aurai prévenues*** !

Given the difference in tense between the English and French phrases, I wonder if I should have expressed the idea of "Don't say you weren't warned!" otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

*“Don't say you weren't warned!”* steps into the future, when the predicted outcome is supposed to have happened. It basically states a likeliness of it happening. Here are some common ways of expressing this in French :

> - *N’allez pas dire après que vous n’étiez pas prévenus !*
> - <sub>A bit tougher, or used with kids, whose inexperience and disobedience commonly end up in injuries (and cries):</sub>
>     *N’allez pas pleurer que vous ne saviez pas !*

On the other hand, *“je vous aurai prévenues !”* is only stating that from this moment, you are not taking responsibility for any possible unpleasant outcome, without clearly stating it will happen. English equivalents could be *“I warned you!”* or *“Consider yourself warned!”*.

Answer (score 1):

That can be:

> Ne dites pas que vous n'étiez pas prévenus (or 'avertis', 'alertés').
>
> Ne dites pas que vous n'aviez pas été prévenus.

Comment: Hi. On another note: With the phrasing "vous (***en***) décourager/dissuader", I wonder if it is more common to drop "en"? Though it is tempting to include it, given the original construction "décourager/dissuader X ***de*** faire Y".

Comment: Hi @Alone-zee. Not sure to get the point of your comment, but, "en" is not mandatory. You can say "Si vous y tenez vraiment, c'est pas moi qui vais vous décourager" will be understood too. But formally the meaning is a bit different as "décourager quelqu'un" or "décourager quelqu'un de faire qq chose" is not exactly the same.

Comment: Just a note, using the "impératif" can be ambiguous, because it could be a current argument about something that was stated in the past. This is used informally, but it would be more correct to use a (longer) sentence such as "Vous ne viendrez pas me dire que vous n'étiez pas prévenues". However, I would argue that trying to match too closely the English idiom is not a good idea, and your "Je vous aurai prévenues" is already a very good fit.